# HTML5/CSS3 expose/pop up moving image after making radio selection

Tags: html, css

With using html/css, How can i expose a moving image after selecting a radio button.

I have tried with the following code, i am able move the text but it always present,i want it to expose after i make a selection. 
for example, if i make a selection of phone radio button, small phone's moving image should pops up from left of screen.

```css
 #rdiv {
         margin: 50px;
         }
         #fradio {
         margin: 15px 10px 20px 180px;
         font-family: fantasy;
         color: chartreuse;
         }
         #sradio {
         margin: 5px 10px 20px 180px;
         font-family: fantasy;
         color: chartreuse;
         }
         @keyframes color-me-in {
         0% {
         background: orange;
         }
         /* Adding a step in the middle */
         50% {
         background: blue;
         }
         100% {
         background: black;
         }
         }
         #fsale {
         vertical-align: middle;
         color: aqua;
         position: relative;
         top: 70%;
         font-size: 3.5em;
         -webkit-animation-name: example;
         /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
         -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
         /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
         animation-name: example;
         animation-duration: 4s;
         animation-iteration-count: infinite;
         }
         @-webkit-keyframes example {
         0% {
         color: red;
         left: 0px;
         top: 0px;
         }
         25% {
         color: yellow;
         top: 200px;
         }
         50% {
         color: blue;
         top: 100px;
         left: 200px;
         }
         75% {
         color: green;
         left: 400px;
         top: 200px;
         }
         100% {
         color: red;
         left: 600px;
         top: 100px;
         }
         }
         #image1 {
         background-image: url(https://hikaricosmetics.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Cabernet-lips-565x565.png);
         }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>External Styles</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
     
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="rdiv">
         <label id="fradio">
         <input type="radio" name="editList" value="never" />phone
         </label>
         <div id="image1"></div>
         <label id="sradio">
         <input type="radio" name="editList" value="costChange" />headphones
         </label>
      </div>
      <p id="fsale">This should be image unpon selection of radio button</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another `@keyframe` to define animation and trigger that by using `#fradio input:checked{}` and `#sradio input:checked{}`

Answer (score 0):

if you use less or sass just need to input keyframes codes inside the #fradio input[type="radio"]:checked

```
#fradio input[type="radio"]:checked {
         @keyframes color-me-in {
         0% {
         background: orange;
         }
         /* Adding a step in the middle */
         50% {
         background: blue;
         }
         100% {
         background: black;
         }
 }
```